# jQuery Google Maps suggestions

Tags: jquery, google-maps

I am developing a parking web application that allows users to upload a pointer on Google Maps showing where their parking space is on the map. I am using jQuery but have not had any luck with anything have been using.

Comment: As per your closed question just now, I recommend you try making a start on this, and ask for help on specific items _after you have tried them_. Break the problem down into small units, and talk to people who assist you - so please acknowledge or converse with @povilasp in the comments below his/her response. Feel free to reply to my comments in your closed question too!

Answer (score 1):

Considering you haven't done anything yet:

http://jquery-ui-map.googlecode.com/

This library could be a great starting point. It helps you build and manipulate maps in a jquerish way, without going deep into details of google maps api.